# How do I bind list with WPF datagrid in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listcollectionview

I cant seem to figure out how to get data from wfp into a list and bind to datagrid.

The xaml form is displaying alright

I have created properties, I created a class to inherit the base class which is code360. I have tried a lot of resources online but not working for me. I tried to hard code the input to see if it will populate the grid but no way. Like this

```
{firstName = "Tim", lastName = "Joy", 
 email = "tim@joy.com", 
 phoneNumber = "0988390243", 
 amount = 200000 }
```

This is mainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace Code360
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class code360
        {
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
            public decimal amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class Code360Manager : List<code360>
        {
            public Code360Manager()
            {
                Add(new code360() {firstName = "Tim", lastName = "Joy", email = "tim@joy.com", phoneNumber = "0988390243", amount = 200000 });
            }
        }

        private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //studentGrid.ItemsSource = Code360Manager();
            MessageBox.Show("This is to test the firstname", firstName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

This is mainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Code360.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Code360"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" FontSize="36"
                   Text="Code360 Student Record" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   Margin="0,0,0,10" />

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="First Name" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBox x:Name="firstName" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" 
                 Width="150" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Text="Last Name" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBox x:Name="lastName" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Width="150" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
                   Text="Email" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBox x:Name="email" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" 
                 Width="150" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"
                   Text="Phone Number" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBox x:Name="phonenumber" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" 
                 Width="150" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
                   Text="Amount" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

            <TextBox x:Name="amount" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" 
                 Width="150" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>


            <Button x:Name="submitButton" Content="Submit" 
                Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" 
                Margin="0,0,0,10" Click="SubmitButton_Click" />

            <DataGrid x:Name="studentGrid"  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="5" MinWidth="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="22,0,45,154" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Code360Manager}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding firstName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding lastName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" 
                                        Binding="{Binding email}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number" Binding="{Binding phonenumber}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding amount}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            </DataGrid>



        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: i can see many mistakes here. but before that i need conform some thing like are wana do it in mvvm ?

Comment: no, Not in MVVM

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to set DataContext.
After InitializeComponent();:
DataContext = this;
Edit: (Sorry. I sent the comments badly).
You need to set the xaml to the context. Generally using a MainWindowViewModel.
I change your code to set the ItemsSource to a List<> instead a class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<code360> Code360Manager { get; set; } = new List<code360>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Code360Manager.Add(new code360() {firstName = "Tim", lastName = "Joy", email = "tim@joy.com", phoneNumber = "0988390243", amount = 200000 });

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //studentGrid.ItemsSource = Code360Manager();
        MessageBox.Show("This is to test the firstname", firstName.Text);
    }
}

public class code360
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain?. Do you mean something like `public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }`

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public List<code360> Code360Manager { get; set; } = new List<code360>();
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Code360Manager.Add(new code360() {firstName ... });
    DataContext = this;
  }
    }

 public class code360
 {
  public string firstName { get; set; }
  public string lastName { get; set; }
  public string email { get; set; }
  public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
  public decimal amount { get; set; }
 }

Answer (score 0):

1.To use `Binding` u need to set the `DataContext` property
so

```
InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = this;
```

2.u need a collection to bind the `DataGrid` in xaml.cs 
`List<code360> MyList { get; set; }`// make sure u have data in this list

3.`ItemsSource` prop will take collection so u need to do bind it with collection
`ItemsSource="{Binding MyList }` `// note the list name is same as the in 2 ponit`

also this is not following mvvm

Comment: The binding is set, provided the resource exists, by the attribute ` ItemsSource="{StaticResource Code360Manager}"` where the DataGrid is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted that code in my Visual Studio and among other things, I came across a problem with this line `ItemsSource="{StaticResource Code360Manager}"`

From the XAML you shared I cannot see where you defiend the resource so consider something like the following.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:Code360Manager x:Key="Code360Manager" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

after the definition of grid and you'll see the datagrid render

Answer (score 0):

A Grid will not take data input as ItemSource, you need to use DataContext. Something like:

```
studentGrid.DataContext = Code360Manager();
```

If it still does not work, try using ListCollectionView as following:

```
ListCollectionView alist = new ListCollectionView(Code360Manager());
studentGrid.DataContext = alist;
```